# Items of a Model are not counting seperatly

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am building a BlogApp and I am stuck on a Problem.

models.py

```
class Album(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',null=True)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts',null=True,blank=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='videos',null=True,blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def new_story(request):
    file = Album.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = {'file':file}
    return render(request, 'mains/new_story.html', context)
```

When i `count` using

> video_limit = Album.objects.filter(user=request.user,video__isnull=False).count()

then it counts `file` objects too BUT i am trying to `count only video objects`.

**What i am trying to do :-**

There are two `fields` in the `Album`model AND I am trying to `count file and video` separately. when i count in the `template` using `{{ file.count }}` then it count all the files and videos BUT when i try to count separately `{{ file.video.count }}` then it is not showing.

I have no idea, how can i count separately.

Comment: see [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/) chapter in Django docs

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko, BUT i don't have `multiple models`.

Comment: yeah, you definitely should read the chapter.

Comment: I already read it before BUT i didn't find `aggregation` with only on model

Comment: you should get error... as `file` does not contain `video`... its a queryset... not a single object...

Comment: the very first example there: `Book.objects.count()`. So if I understand correctly, you want count how many `Album` items user have with non-empty `file` or `video`? `Album.objects.filter(user=request.user, video__isnull=False).count()`

Comment: It is counting `file` object too. BUT i am trying to count only `video` objects.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko, That is the main problem, that it is counting `file` objects too with video. BUT i want to count only `video` objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{ file.video.count }}` is empty because file is a queryset and it has no "video" property.

You can achieve what you want without using aggregates.  The easiest way is to store the video count separately and pass it to the context:

```
def new_story(request):
    file = Album.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    video_count = file.filter(video__isnull=False).count()
    context = {
        'file': file,
        'video_count': video_count
    }
    return render(request, 'mains/new_story.html', context)
```

And in your template, you can just use `{{ video_count }}`

**UPDATE**:

Try to replace video_count with the following:

```
video_count = file.exclude(video='').count()
```

or

```
from django.db.models import Q
video_count = file.filter(Q(video__isnull=True) | ~Q(video='')).count()
```

Comment: Thank you for your Effort . BUT It is still counting `file` objects too. AND i am just try to count `video objects` .

Comment: When i add file ( Not Video ) and count the video then numbers increases

Comment: can you try `video_count = file.exclude(video='').count()`?